# NO user can log into the org as a result of profile change

Tags: administration, profile, security

We have a developer org and all of the users (including the admins) in the org have the same profile and the profile was mistakenly updated to have NO rights. (simplified version of the story). Now all of the users have the same profile (Salesforce Licence) that has no access to change anything.

I have already logged a case with Salesforce. I was wondering if you can think of ideas we can try to revert the changes or somehow change the profile for one of the users so we can log back in.

Comment: Unless losing this account directly affects an AppExchange product, you're probably out of luck. Should you manage to recover your account, I suggest adding an answer here. In my experience, developers and even employees that lock themselves out of a free account can never recover it.

Comment: Yeah I think same. 99.99 % it's gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an ISV partner, we could get a hold of Salesforce support tier 2. They can see all the access rights of profiles and have 100% visibility into the org. They realized the profile had been changed to API Only and suggested doing an update using Data Loader. Using Force.com API tool would also work (requires access to the security token).

They could potentially fix the profile directly, but said would need a letter from a senior executive to do that for security reasons.